# JButtons in JPanel take too much space

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, gridbaglayout

i have a problem with some buttons and panels. I created a JPanel with a GridBagLayout 6x1.

```
        GraphicPaintedPanel deck = new GraphicPaintedPanel();
        GridBagLayout gblDecks = new GridBagLayout();                                               
        gblDecks.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gblDecks.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gblDecks.columnWeights = new double[]{0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gblDecks.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        deck.setLayout(gblDecks);
```

The problem comes when i try to add buttons to this panel as they take space based on how many they are, even tho they should have fixed size. For example if I do

```
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
            JButton activate= new JButton("ACTIVATE LEADER CARD");
            GridBagConstraints gbcActivate = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbcActivate.gridx = j;
            gbcActivate.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            deck.add(activate, gbcActivate);
            }
```

I create 4 buttons and the panel is supposed to have 4 button and 2 "empty spaces". But instead it ha 4 buttons that take all the space they can.[image]

If i do

```
            for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            JButton activate= new JButton("ACTIVATE LEADER CARD");
            GridBagConstraints gbcActivate = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbcActivate.gridx = j;
            gbcActivate.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            deck.add(activate, gbcActivate);
            }
```

I get this instead[image]

Shouldn't the dimensions be fixed? Can anyone help me?

Comment: As I don't have a [mcve] from you to test with, tell me what happens if you remove this line: `gbcActivate.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;`?

Comment: Exactly what @Frakcool says.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for an explanation of what each constraint is used for. You can also use a simpler layout manger like `FlowLayout`.

Comment: gbcActivate.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; tells the component to take all the space it can within THE SAME CELL, it can't make a button exceed its space given by the layout, and in FlowLayout you can't set the dimension in %, gridbagLayout you can

Comment: Tip, add @HovercraftFullOfEels or whoever you want to reply to, so they get notified of your reply... and again, for better help sooner post a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

`gbcActivate.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH`

If we go to the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) it says:

> **fill** 
>   Used when the component's display area is larger than the component's requested size to determine whether and how to resize the component. Valid values (defined as GridBagConstraints constants) include NONE (the default), HORIZONTAL (make the component wide enough to fill its display area horizontally, but do not change its height), VERTICAL (make the component tall enough to fill its display area vertically, but do not change its width), **and BOTH (make the component fill its display area entirely).**

So, it will fill the display area independtly of what you specify for the `columnWeights`, etc. Try removing it or changing it for `GridBagConstraints.NONE`

Or as suggested in the comments above, use another [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) such as [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow)